# the meaning of the phrase"practical folks"

Tags: phrases

What is the meaning of *practical folks in the following passage?

> Enjoy learning. While practical folks will say college is about getting the piece of paper that will get you the job. I hope you will see it more than that.

Comment: Look up "practical" in a dictionary, and also look up "pragmatic".

Answer (score 1):

I think it means people who think academic knowledge is not always relevant to the realities of the world.

From Cambridge Dictionary

```
relating to actual experience or to the use of knowledge in activities rather than to knowledge only or ideas
```